# Node app inside docker cannot connect to another node app

Tags: node.js, docker

So both apps are inside docker. Both go through nginx upstream:

```
upstream api {
    server api:5000;
}

upstream search {
    server search:5001;
}

server {
...

location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass  http://api;
}

location /search {
    rewrite /search/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass  http://search;
}
```

Going with browser or even curl to

```
http://localhost/api/
```

and to

```
http://localhost/search/ works.
```

When inside one of the apps, I try to go to the other:

```
//const url = "http://localhost/search/search/test";
const url = "http://localhost:5001";
request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log('error:',error);
    console.log('response:',response);
    console.log('body:',body);
});
```

I tried both urls. But in both cases the response is the same:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5001
```

In docker-compose, I have this:

```yaml
api:
  restart: always
  build:
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    context: ./server
  volumes:
    - /app/node_modules
    - ./server:/app
  links:
    - mongo
    - elasticsearch
    - search
  ports:
    - '5000:5000'
  environment:
    - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
  depends_on:
    - mongo
    
search:
  restart: always
  build:
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    context: ./search
  volumes:
    - /app/node_modules
    - ./search:/app
  links:
    - elasticsearch
  ports:
    - '5001:5001'
  environment:
    - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
```

Why is this happening? I also have another app, a client in react. That app can connect to api. So im struggling trying to understand why this two node apps cannot communicate with each other.

Comment: did you try with the container name? ```url = "http://search:5001";```

Comment: I did it now and it works. However, it only works if I go directly through the port: http://search:5001. So it wont go through nginx.

Comment: so, where is the nginx? it is another container?

Comment: yes, nginx is in another container specified in docker-compose.

Comment: please, take a look on my answer, and please complete the Docker Compose

Comment: Oderfla please take a look at @German answer. If it works, please mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is you are mapping your (local)host ports to the container port, that is why you can reach localhost:5000 and localhost:5001.

From the cointainer point of view they don´t know each other as localhost, each one is it own localhost.

I can see you have a mongo cointainer, how did you reach mongo?

You can make 2 things: 1st, create a virtual network, give each container an IP and comunicate them using that IP; or 2nd thing, use the named container and make your "API" container comunicates with "Search" container with its name, using `url = "http://search:5001"`

If you have a 3rd container with the nginx, so you need to use its name `http://nginx:port/search`  instead of `search`